# .NET ConfigurationErrorsException: The element <..> may only appear once in this section

Tags: c#, xml

I am creating a class to read/write the custom configuration from the the configuration file. Here is the configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<configuration>   
<configSections>
 <section name="Country" type="CustomeConfig.CountryConfig, CustomeConfig"/>  
</configSections>   
<Country>
    <State>
      <City>
        <add name="a" age="20"></add>
        <add name="b" age="20"></add>
        <add name="c" age="20"></add>
      </City>
      <City>
        <add name="d" age="20"></add>
        <add name="e" age="20"></add>
        <add name="f" age="20"></add>
      </City>
    </State>  
 </Country>
 </configuration>
```

and the code to read the configuration file is below

```
 namespace CustomeConfig
    {
        public class CountryConfig : ConfigurationSection
        {
        [ConfigurationProperty("State")]
        public StateCollection States
        {
            get { return ((StateCollection)(base["State"])); }
        }
    }


    [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(CityCollection))]
    public class StateCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
    {

        protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
        {
            return new CityCollection();
        }

        protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
        {
            return ((CityCollection)(element));
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("City", IsDefaultCollection = false)]
        public CityCollection this[int idx]
        {
            get
            {
                return (CityCollection)BaseGet(idx);
            }
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(User))]
    public class CityCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
    {

        protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
        {
            return new User();
        }

        protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
        {
            return ((User)(element)).name;
        }

        public User this[int idx]
        {
            get
            {
                return (User)BaseGet(idx);
            }
        }

        //public override ConfigurationElementCollectionType CollectionType
        //{
        //    get { return ConfigurationElementCollectionType.BasicMap; }
        //}
    }


    public class User : ConfigurationElement
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("name", DefaultValue = "", IsKey = true, IsRequired = true)]
        public string name
        {
            get { return (string)base["name"]; }
            set { base["name"] = value; }
        }
        [ConfigurationProperty("age", DefaultValue = "", IsKey = false, IsRequired = true)]
        public string servername
        {
            get { return (string)base["age"]; }
            set { base["age"] = value; }
        }
    }

}



    static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                CountryConfig config = (CountryConfig)System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.GetConfig("Country");


                Console.ReadLine();
            }
```

as soon as I run the code it's shows the error "The element `<city>` may only appear once in this section". Since there are two `<city>` section.

Answer (score 0):

If I run into problems with configuration sections I usually start with no data in my section within the xml file. Then I populate the data via code and save it. Then you can easily figure out what you have done wrong within the xml.

Put this in your Custom section in order to be able to save a code populated section:

```
public void Save()
{
    Configuration config = 
            ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(spath);
    CountryConfig section = (CountryConfig)config.Sections["Country"];
    section.States = this.States; //Copy the changed data
    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);
}
```

So then you can work from your C# code to work out how the configuration should be structured (helps to spot inconsistencies between the two)